# Override properties in Spring Boot Profiles at command prompt

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I know how to change certain properties in application.properties when I launch my application by:

```
java -jar myjar.jar --my.option=newValue
```

Now I created 2 Spring profiles for multiple environments. I have only 1 line in application.properties to define what the active profile is, and all my options are in different profile files like below setup.

```
application.properties
application-DH.properties
application-HA.properties
```

Now if I want to change options defined in those 2 profile properties files, how can I do so? I tried the same I used to and it turns my.option is nothing instead of newValue.

Comment: You might want to read: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments

Comment: @Nikolas I read and tried. I can only change arguments in application.properties but not those in profile specific ones.